# Finding the frequency of a sine wave in the microphone

Tags: windows, audio, frequency

I am looking for a way to get the frequency of a sine wave from a tape recorder plugged into a microphone socket on a Windows PC. It's for a small project I'm working on to see if I can store data on sound tapes, so I'll be reading and writing frequencies to the tape to store data.

Thanks

Comment: Any programming language requirements?  Will you record to a .wav file and then process the wav file, or are you streaming the data in realtime?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't? Note that you aren't getting a single clear wave from the microphone at any time. Anyway, you may want to look at the methods used by the Ancient Geeks, so that you don't end up reinventing a square wheel - e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum_software#Tape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to estimate the frequency of a sine wave is doing a spectrum analysis and look for the "loudest" frequency (roughly):

1. take one chunk of audio (for example 256 samples) from the audio
   file, or from the audio input
2. window the audio chunk ^
3. compute its power spectrum (using an FFT algorithm^^)
4. look for the dominant frequency, which should be the frequency of the sine wave
5. repeat until you have audio data

I expect it to work well with simple tones.

^ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

^^ there are plenty of FFT implementations available, for example http://www.fftw.org/

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one sine wave at any given time, you can count how many times per second the signal changes its value from positive to negative (IOW, crosses 0) or the other way around and that will give you the frequency. Or you can measure the time between consecutive zero crossings. This is a pretty simple and cheap solution.